# How do I download all mail from my POP server?

Tags: macos, gmail, download, pop3, apple-mail

Does anyone know how I can download all mail from my Gmail server via POP? I am using Mail on a Mac.

Answer (score 3):

There is an article from Google on [Backing up your email with POP](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=34030&topic=1556).